# Error running twisted application

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to run a simple twisted application echo bot that metajack blogged about, everything looks like it is going to load fine, but at the very end I get an error:

```
2009/07/12 15:46 -0600 [-] ImportError: cannot import name toResponse
2009/07/12 15:46 -0600 [-] Failed to load application: cannot import name toResponse
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

I've not played with wokkel/twisted/python at all and dont know where to start to look.

It is worth nothing that I've tried another wokkel/twisted app and got this very same error.

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused because I have an outdated version of Twisted.  Off to find a way to update twisted itself as the installer doesnt seem to be doing the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really enough information to go on, but if I had to guess, I'd say that you've given your program the same name as one of the modules that it relies on.  Try renaming it to `anthonys_echo_bot.py` and re-running it.  Do this:

```
rm *.pyc
```

in the directory in which you're running it first.

If that doesn't help, you'll need to track down the piece of code that's trying import `toResponse` - is that all the error you get?  No traceback, pointing to lines of code?

Comment: Orig Code:
http://metajack.im/2008/09/25/an-xmpp-echo-bot-with-twisted-and-wokkel/?dsq=12557043#comment-12557043

2009/07/12 15:51 -0600 [-]   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/wokkel/client.py", line 18, in <module>
2009/07/12 15:51 -0600 [-]   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/wokkel/generic.py", line 14, in <module>
2009/07/12 15:51 -0600 [-] ImportError: cannot import name toResponse
2009/07/12 15:51 -0600 [-] Failed to load application: cannot import name toResponse

Running this code gives the same error as above:
http://wokkel.ik.nu/browser/trunk/doc/examples/pinger_client.tac

Comment: in wokkel (generic.py) it imports toResponse with:

from twisted.words.protocols.jabber.xmlstream import toResponse

Is there any reason why it would not be able to import that?

Comment: toResponse is def'd here, line 822: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/words/protocols/jabber/xmlstream.py

Comment: funny enough my version of xmlstream.py is only like 697 lines and the one in the link above is like double that.  Odd since I just installed twisted fresh today using the binary on the site.